# Встраивание видео с youtube на сайт

Tags: php, html, youtube

Необходимо встроить видео с youtube на сайт через iframe. Можно ли это сделать, имея url видео с youtube, не обращаясь к кнопке "Встроить"?

Например, у нас есть видео
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть его url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOFJ7elRH1o

Для того, чтобы его встроить на сайт необходимо знать только значение GET параметра 'v'?

В нашем случае, оно = mOFJ7elRH1o

Тогда url для встраивания: [https://www.youtube.com/embed/$_GET['v']](https://www.youtube.com/embed/$_GET%5B%27v%27%5D)

В нашем случае: https://www.youtube.com/embed/mOFJ7elRH1o

Comment: какой, какой url?

Comment: Вы вроде сами всё расписали, в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: А от нас что хотите? Чтобы код написали?

Answer (score 1):

не понял вопроса, но если у вас не выводится [https://www.youtube.com/embed/$_GET['v']](https://www.youtube.com/embed/$_GET%5B%27v%27%5D), то возможно вы не присвоили параметру v вашу ссылку. Могу порекомендовать создать БД phpmy admin, где будут хранится все ссылки и их можна будет вывести по id. Но я не понимаю зачем. Разве что у вас этих ссылок 100 и вам их нужно в ряд вывести 1 функцией, что бы следовать правилу DRY и не засорять код. Если вам нужно вывести 1 видео, просто укажите ссылку и не парьтесь